# simultaneous download using download.file

Tags: r, download

Since the version 3.2.1, the [official](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/NEWS.pdf) R document says that there is support for simultaneous downloads. Following is the quoted text from help file:

*Support for method "libcurl" is optional: use capabilities("libcurl") to see if it is supported on your build. It provides (non-blocking) access to https:// and ftps:// URLs. There is support for simultaneous downloads, so url and destfile can be character vectors of the same length greater than one. For a single URL and quiet = FALSE there a progress bar is shown in interactive use.*

But when I tried to download two files from two different websites, it downloaded only one:

```
url_list<-c("http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-exts.html","http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/NEWS.pdf")
dest_list<-c("test1.html","test2.pdf")
download.file(url_list,dest_list)

trying URL 'http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-exts.html'
Content type 'text/html' length 874175 bytes (853 KB)
downloaded 853 KB

Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url_list, dest_list) :
  only first element of 'url' argument used
2: In download.file(url_list, dest_list) :
  only first element of 'destfile' argument used
```

Then, I saw that I missed using an argument `method="libcurl"`

```
download.file(url_list,dest_list,method="libcurl").
```

Once I run this command in RStudio: R Studio gives fatal warning and R session gets aborted. With the R for Windows GUI, the following warning occurs (and then shut down):

*R for Windows GUI front-end has stopped working. 
"A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.".*

I am using Windows 8.0. I also ran `capabilities("libcurl")` and it gives the following output.

```
libcurl 
   TRUE
```

Comment: It works for me on Linux. You probably need something else on Windows.

Comment: I think it should also work in Windows .  May be I am missing something here.

Comment: Hum, I just checked and it works on R but not on R through RStudio.

Comment: Yes, right, on Linux.

Comment: Since it seems to be failing on GUI's regardless of system, could it be due to the progress bar? What if `quiet=TRUE` is set?

Comment: @thelatemail Of course!

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail: The problem is solved.

Comment: You should consider filing this as a bug if it hasn't been already. Forced program closes probably aren't a good thing to have in a basic 'utils' function.

Comment: I haven't done that. I will now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the comment of @thelatemail: setting `quiet=TRUE` gives the desired result (which means it is due to the progress bar):

```
download.file(url_list,dest_list,method="libcurl",quiet=TRUE)
```